# Catching Uncaught Typerrors in Javascript

Tags: javascript, error-handling, undefined

Getting the following error

```
Uncaught Typerror : Cannot read property 'foo' of undefined
```

The offending line is

```
s2 = targets[j].foo*4;
```

Obviously I should fix the source of the problem, but in the meantime, how can i properly wrap the offending line so it doesn't throw an error and break my application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrapping the code in a try catch lets you handle issues like this.

```
try {
    s2 = targets[j].foo * 4;
} catch (exception) {
    console.error(exception.stack);
}
```

Instead of

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: targets is not defined
```

(because I do not even have targets defined) I now get

```
ReferenceError: targets is not defined
    at snippets:///424_2145:2:10
```

But you're right, you should really find the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

The likely cause of the error is that `targets[j]` for that particular index is null.

Try this

```
s2 = targets[j] && targets[j].foo ? targets[j].foo * 4 : 0;
```

Here you can set the value of s2 to a default value(I am setting it to 0) if `targets[j]` is null or undefined.

Again this will just fix the symptom but not the source of your problem.